# FTP. How to list files in current directory at the server

Tags: ftp, network-programming, client-server

How would i list the files in the current directory at the server, and change the current directory to other directory at the server. This is what my FTP server looks like along with the FTP client. I got it to check if the file is there, and if it is a duplicate. But if I type cd in the terminal, it causes the sever to go into an infinite loop.

```
 public class FTPServer{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket soc=new ServerSocket(5217);
        System.out.println("FTP Server Started on Port Number 5217");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Connection ...");
            transferfile t=new transferfile(soc.accept());
        }
    }
}

class transferfile extends Thread
{
    Socket ClientSoc;

    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;

    transferfile(Socket soc)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientSoc=soc;                      
            din=new DataInputStream(ClientSoc.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(ClientSoc.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("FTP Client Connected ...");
            start();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }       
    }
    void SendFile() throws Exception
    {       
        String filename=din.readUTF();
        File f=new File(filename);
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            dout.writeUTF("File Not Found");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            dout.writeUTF("READY");
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
            int ch;
            do
            {
                ch=fin.read();
                dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
            }
            while(ch!=-1);  
            fin.close();    
            dout.writeUTF("File Receive Successfully");                         
        }
    }

    void ReceiveFile() throws Exception
    {
        String filename=din.readUTF();
        if(filename.compareTo("File not found")==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        File f=new File(filename);
        String option;

        if(f.exists())
        {
            dout.writeUTF("File Already Exists");
            option=din.readUTF();
        }
        else
        {
            dout.writeUTF("SendFile");
            option="Y";
        }

            if(option.compareTo("Y")==0)
            {
                FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(f);
                int ch;
                String temp;
                do
                {
                    temp=din.readUTF();
                    ch=Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    if(ch!=-1)
                    {
                        fout.write(ch);                 
                    }
                }while(ch!=-1);
                fout.close();
                dout.writeUTF("File Send Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

    }


    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Command ...");
            String Command=din.readUTF();
            if(Command.compareTo("GET")==0)
            {
                System.out.println("\tGET Command Received ...");
                SendFile();
                continue;
            }
            else if(Command.compareTo("SEND")==0)
            {
                System.out.println("\tSEND Command Receiced ...");              
                ReceiveFile();
                continue;
            }
            else if(Command.compareTo("DISCONNECT")==0)
            {
                System.out.println("\tDisconnect Command Received ...");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

class FTPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5217);
        transferfileClient t=new transferfileClient(soc);
        t.displayMenu();

    }
}
class transferfileClient
{
    Socket ClientSoc;

    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    BufferedReader br;
    transferfileClient(Socket soc)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientSoc=soc;
            din=new DataInputStream(ClientSoc.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(ClientSoc.getOutputStream());
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }       
    }
    void SendFile() throws Exception
    {       

        String filename;
        System.out.print("Enter File Name :");
        filename=br.readLine();

        File f=new File(filename);
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File not Exists...");
            dout.writeUTF("File not found");
            return;
        }

        dout.writeUTF(filename);

        String msgFromServer=din.readUTF();
        if(msgFromServer.compareTo("File Already Exists")==0)
        {
            String Option;
            System.out.println("File Already Exists. Want to OverWrite (Y/N) ?");
            Option=br.readLine();           
            if(Option=="Y") 
            {
                dout.writeUTF("Y");
            }
            else
            {
                dout.writeUTF("N");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sending File ...");
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch=fin.read();
            dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
        while(ch!=-1);
        fin.close();
        System.out.println(din.readUTF());

    }

    void ReceiveFile() throws Exception
    {
        String fileName;
        System.out.print("Enter File Name :");
        fileName=br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(fileName);
        String msgFromServer=din.readUTF();

        if(msgFromServer.compareTo("File Not Found")==0)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found on Server ...");
            return;
        }
        else if(msgFromServer.compareTo("READY")==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Receiving File ...");
            File f=new File(fileName);
            if(f.exists())
            {
                String Option;
                System.out.println("File Already Exists. Want to OverWrite (Y/N) ?");
                Option=br.readLine();           
                if(Option=="N") 
                {
                    dout.flush();
                    return; 
                }               
            }
            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(f);
            int ch;
            String temp;
            do
            {
                temp=din.readUTF();
                ch=Integer.parseInt(temp);
                if(ch!=-1)
                {
                    fout.write(ch);                 
                }
            }while(ch!=-1);
            fout.close();
            System.out.println(din.readUTF());

        }


    }

    public void displayMenu() throws Exception
    {
        while(true)
        {   
            System.out.println("[ MENU ]");
            System.out.println("1. Send File");
            System.out.println("2. Receive File");
            System.out.println("3. Exit");
            System.out.print("\nEnter Choice :");
            int choice;
            choice=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if(choice==1)
            {
                dout.writeUTF("SEND");
                SendFile();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                dout.writeUTF("GET");
                ReceiveFile();
            }
            else
            {
                dout.writeUTF("DISCONNECT");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```